# Special Price not displaying on Wishlist

Tags: magento2, wishlist, magento-2.1.8, pricing

**UPDATE** - This is a reported isue in v2.1 but there is not fix for it.

In Magento 2 special prices do not seem to be displayed on the Wishlists page.

Is it possible to display these? How? Is there any reason why they would not be displayed here?

See images below, the €12 discount is shown on the product page and not the wishlist page.

Is this possible with layoutXML, when I look in `wishlist_index_index.xml` I see:

```
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="item/column/price.phtml" cacheable="false">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.wishlist">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">wishlist_configured_price</argument>
            <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_list</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" cacheable="false"/>
</block>
```

I know I can use similar LayoutXML in my theme, but what would I need to add to change it?

So far I've tried variations of the below, but it doesn't change anything:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.price.render.wishlist">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">wishlist_configured_price</argument>
        <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_list</argument>
    </arguments>
    <arguments>
        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
        <argument name="display_msrp_help_message" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
        <argument name="id_suffix" xsi:type="string">copy-</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

---

### Wishlist Page

[image]

### Product Page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your Magento version. But, for my Magento 2.2.0 version, the price display is the special price on the wishlist page by default. So, in your case, try to reindex database.

If you want to show regular price as well, we can achieve that easily by changing `price_type_code` to `final_price`.

app/code/Vendor/Wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.price.render.wishlist">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Khoa, I'm using v2.1.8, this has been fixed in 2.2 but nothing I can't find anything available to fix it in 2.1 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11305

Comment: I tried that xml on my version and it does not work :(

Comment: I will check on my Magento 2.1.7 version. And then let you know.

Comment: I could not get it working on ver. 2.1.8 either

Comment: If checking `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist/Item/Column/Cart.php`, we can see the product doesn't contain special price data. I'm debugging on this issue.